# Android App Development - Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an activity in an app where users can upload a post, and other users in the app can view the post.

I built a function called `loadPost()`
This function will take what's there in the database and load it in my View.
Unfortunately, I'm facing an error with the

```
 .addValueEventListener(ValueEventListener{
```

It's telling me that the interface needs a constructor.

here's the function:

```
//*******************************************************
//Load posts to the screen from the database
//****************************************************
fun loadPost(){

  myRef.child("posts")
    .addValueEventListener(ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(@NonNull dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {

            try {
                postElements.clear()
                postElements.add(Post("0","him","url","add"))
                postElements.add(Post("0","him","url","ads"))

                //Hashmap : Key and value (represents the post and node)
                var td= dataSnapshot!!.value as HashMap<String,Any>

                for(key in td.keys){
                    var post= td[key] as HashMap<String,Any>

                    postElements.add(Post(key,
                            post["text"] as String,
                            post["postImage"] as String
                            ,post["userUID"] as String))
                }

                adpater!!.notifyDataSetChanged() //notify when there's an update in the adapter
            }catch (ex:Exception){}
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {

        }
    })

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "It's telling me that the interface needs a constructor", nice try, but could you be a little more specific about the problem? because I would rather say, that **an interface cannot have constructors**, by design.

Comment: Yes, an interface can't have a constructor. However, that's what the compiler shows.

Comment: Any idea how to implement the  .addValueEventListener?

Comment: Sorry. This is the message:

Comment: Interface ValueEventListener does not have constructors

Comment: @RasheedAlRasheed Please paste here the entire error that you get and the specific line at which it occurs. Please responde with @.

Answer (score 0):

this is how the constructor of a `ValueEventListener` should look alike:

```
object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

    }
}
```

which means, that you have to replace this one line

```
.addValueEventListener(ValueEventListener {
```

with:

```
.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
```

see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770 (concerning the code-converter)